# Spark: add Option column to DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to add an `Option` column to a DataFrame, so I wrote this code:

```
val newDataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("newColumn", lit(Some(true)))
```

this fails with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.Some Some(true)
```

So it seams that `Option` is not a literal. What would be the right way of adding an `Option` column to a DataFrame?

Comment: Use plain `Java` `null`s? Read [Dealing with null in Spark](https://www.mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dealing-with-null)

Comment: I agree with @y2k-shubham, you should try with something like `lit(null)`

Comment: The whole concept is a little odd.